# moving a database from one server to another that is not connected

Tags: sql-server

thrown into a dba role. I have two servers, neither one is connected to a network. How would I get a db from one of them to the other? Would I need to do a select all and export and then import into the other after I created a new db that matches the other?

Thanks.

Comment: By far the easiest way to copy a database to another server is to make a backup, then copy the backup file to the new server and restore the backup on the new server. But I have to question that you have two servers that are not connected to a network? Kind of defeats the concept of being a server.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you copy the database backup files or detached database files - over the network, on a USB stick or a DVD. Restoring is the same. Reattaching is the same

Comment: The company had an attack so now they don't have them connected. How would I create and copy the backup? Sorry.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Sql injection?

Comment: Backup the db with compression. Depending on the backup file size, you can use a large usb stick or a large usb portal drive,

Comment: If they just had a cyber attack, I'd advocate for a real DBA to help them get going again. Alas, some companies never learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no connectivity between them, you got only way to use external storage drive to transfer the database. In your case to move/copy complete database you can use anyone of following options:

Before proceeding consider the SQL Server version (you can identify executing `select @@version`) because the database or it's backups cannot be restored into lower version i.e. if you taking backup form SQL 2012 it can be only restored on SQL 2012 or higher

Hope you got [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) installed and ready in both servers which is essential to do management activities:

**[Backup and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/quickstart-backup-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017)** - Summarized steps

1. Login to **Source** SQL Server locally, connect external storage drive
2. Perform backup and store the backups in external storage
3. Remove external storage drive from Source server and connect it to **Destination** Server
4. Login to **Destination** SQL Server locally, perform restore from backup file (that stored in external drive)

[**Copy MDF and LDF files**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases?view=sql-server-2017)  - Summarized steps

1. Login to **Source** SQL Server locally, connect external storage drive
2. Set target database to `offline`. Copy `.MDF`, `.NDF` (if exists) and `.LDF` files into external storage drive
3. Remove external storage drive from Source server and connect it to **Destination** Server
4. Login to **Destination** SQL Server locally, copy the files form external storage and paste into same directory as source server.
5. Perform [Attach database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017)